# How to Default A Value in a Filter

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

In Tableau I have the field Properties. Based on the incoming data, these names can change. But, there is one value that will always be constant which is the name 'Market Average'. How can I make it so no matter what, on the checkboxes, this value is always selected and the others are unchecked? When new data is loaded the others names will change, except for Market Value. And we want it this way because we don't want a bunch of data for all the different properties getting loaded. This serves so the dashboard looks clean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYUWp.png

Answer (score 1):

Publish or save your workbook with only 'Market Average' selected in your Properties filter just as you have in your image.

When you open desktop or someone views this dashboard on Tableau Server, it will in essence default to only having 'Market Average' selected. If you have the filter shown somewhere on the dashboard, users will still be able to interact with it even as the other names change.